# How to place carriage Return in HTTP Header value

Tags: vb.net, http, http-headers

I have an HTTP web request that looks something like the following:

```
    Dim myrequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("myURL")
    myrequest.Proxy = Nothing
    myrequest.UserAgent = "AGENT"
    myrequest.Method = "POST"
    myrequest.ContentLength = 0

    myrequest.Headers.Add("KEY1", value)
    myrequest.Headers.Add("KEY2", value)


    Dim myresponse As HttpWebResponse = myrequest.GetResponse
    Dim mystream As System.IO.Stream = (myresponse.GetResponseStream)

    Dim streamreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(mystream)
    return streamreader.ReadToEnd
```

The problem is that I cannot send any of the following values to place a line break in a header value.  So far, I have tried :

vbNewLine

vbCrLf

vbCR

vbLF

These produce an error that says "Specified value has invalid CRLF characters"  I have also tried

\n

\r\n

And it just adds the string literals to my value and does not include a carriage return.  On the server side I would like to take what value is included in this header and place into a column in MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Http Headers must not contain a new line as this is defined as the header separator.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3 and especially https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6.

Comment: Thank you.  I worked around this by adding the text "<LINEBREAK>" in the header, and then using the string replace function in PHP.   I assume that the "correct" way would be to include the values in the request body instead?

Comment: Yes, the request body would be the right place. Or maybe base64 encode your value ( wears header length limitations).

Comment: I just ran into an issue with owin throwing an `ArgumentException` because I proxied a request from a third party app that in fact used a line break in a header value. I figured out it is allowed but you have to prepend the next line with a space or tab, see: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html (i.e. `KEY=hello\r\n world`). `owin didn't complain anymore so I suppose this is a valid solution.